# i have 2 table in db i want to print repeated value only one time

Tags: php, mysql

this is my php code for sql query its giving me same value multi time

```
if (isset($_GET["q"]))
 {

   $q= $_GET["q"];

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysqli_select_db($link,"onesports");
$result=mysqli_query($link,"select  players.full_name, team.* from players,team where team.team_name='" .$q. " ' and players.team_name=team.team_name ");



echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<a href=>" . $row['full_name'] . "</a>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['team_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prov'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['captain'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['coach'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


}
else {
   echo "no result found.";

}
```

its giving me this output 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNXmC.png)

i want only player name and remaining value want for one time

Comment: [BobbyTables](https://xkcd.com/327/) - You're at very high risk af sql injection!! Use prepared statements.

Comment: please describe what the relation between player an team is. The image isn't really helpful, because we don't know what text could be what (is 'kingkarachi' a team? or is it 'king'? Is 'arbaz' really the players name??

Comment: this `<a href=>` also doesn't look right...

Comment: I'm confused. If you only want the full name, just stop outputting everything other than the name? "remaining value want" I'm not sure I understand what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `INNER JOIN` in this case.

just update your code with below code.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `players`.full_name,`team`.* FROM `players` INNER JOIN `team` ON  `players`.team_name= `team`.team_name AND `team`.team_name='".$q."'");
```